# Where can I find Rest API Endpoint in Oracle Cloud?

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am unable to find the rest api endpoint in oracle cloud portal. If someone could please help me locate the epi endpoint URL, it would be really great.
Format for Oracle Cloud Api:

https://{api_endpoint}/{resource_base_path}/{resource_name}

I am not able to find this "{api_endpoint}".Please help me out.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific - Oracle Cloud Infrastructure has a lot of different endpoints, depending on your country and what service you're trying to connect to. See this list: https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/apiref.htm

Comment: Actally I was looking for OCI-C(Oracle Cloud infrastructure Compute Classic) endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [here](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/apiref.htm) for all OCI cloud service API endpoints.